# Search for installed Map apps on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to get a list of the installed apps which provide Map functionality?

In the maps settings menu, you can select which app should be the default one for voice navigation - in that list, my phone displays HereDrive+ and Windows Phone Maps.

How is it possible to search for apps like this? Is such API open or that list result was acquired using a restricted API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a correct answer, but maybe the way you should use this is by using the ms-drive-to or ms-walk-to Uri scheme! When you use those, the phone itself will launch HERE drive if it is present, otherwise Bing maps!

My guess, in the future the user will be able so set this as an option, that he can indicate what default map app he wants to use in general. But for now it's default Bing or HERE if that is installed when using the given URI scheme.

Get the needed example code and usage on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! It makes sense to use the Nokia apps instead of the standard WP ones. But I'd need to actually use Here Maps not Here Drive+. I will look into those URI schemes more deeply.

Comment: Right now, I have already implemented the Here Maps launch using a Geopoint using "exploremaps" URI scheme : http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/wp-uri-schemes-for-location-applications.html But I would go for HereMaps service first and only WP standard apps as a fallback

Comment: Good call! By the way if I look at the reserved list there is also a generic 'maps.' one - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx not sure if you can manipulate that one with extra properties though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to list apps like this. The referenced settings menu is part of the OS not an exertion point for apps.
Apps are blocked from setting information like this from other apps or the OS.

Comment: This is bad news for me... I am displaying a map location in my app using a Map control. On tap, I wanted to display a list of possible apps installed on the phone which can further handle a Geopoint location and continue the flow in a Map-specialized app. So far, I've thought of Maps default app which should absolutely work and also, the HereMaps app from Nokia. I launch a URI to display the location in HereMaps but a problem right now, is that I am unsure how to check whether HereMaps package is installed on the current device or not. @RobCaplan, do you have any suggestions how to handle?